# Return will return empty object even it shoudn't

Tags: mysql, node.js

here is my code

```
  (email) => {
    let con = {};
    connection.query(
      "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?",
      email,
      (error, result) => {
        con.id = result[0].id;
        con.email = result[0].email;
        con.name = result[0].name;
        con.password = result[0].password;
      }
    );
    return con;
  },
```

It's simple, it should return con object, but it returns it empty. I think because this query will execute last in function. Any help?

Comment: I assign it here: `let con = {};` I think this query will execute last in this function? Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to turn your function into `async` and wrap `connection.query` with `new Promise` like this:

```js
(email) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      connection.query(
        "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?",
        email,
        (error, result) => {
          if (error) {
            reject(error);
          }
          const con = {};
          con.id = result[0].id;
          con.email = result[0].email;
          con.name = result[0].name;
          con.password = result[0].password;
          resolve(con);
        }
      );
  }
```

And using it like this:

```js
func(email).then(con => {
  console.log(con)
});
```

or with `await`:

```js
const con = await func(email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right, the query will take a bit of time and `con` will be already returned by the time it finishes running.

Even if it doesn't take any time, the callback function is going to be run separately so `con` will not be updated either way.

You have two options:

- use a promise version of the `query()` method if it's available.
- promise-ify the query.

This is roughly how you can do it (2nd option):

```
return new Promise((resolve) => {
  connection.query(
  "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email=?",
  email,
  (error, result) => {
    let con = {};
    con.id = result[0].id;
    con.email = result[0].email;
    con.name = result[0].name;
    con.password = result[0].password;
    resolve(con);
  }
});

...
// and you can use it like this
const result = await myFunc(email);
```